# SQL syntax error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

If someone can explain why doesnt work, i would apriciate :)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''categorias'' at line 1

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'categorias' ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while ($categorias = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<p>" . $categorias ['descricao'] . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from your table name.  Instead use back ticks if needed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM categorias ";
```

Or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `categorias` ";
```

Comment: It worked! now it tells me i'm not connected to the DB